# Как отправить фото или документы через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

как можно сразу отправить файлы через ajax когда мы чтото закинули в Input type="file", мой скрипт почему то не срабатывают буду признателен за помощь

```
<form action="/profile/uploadFiles" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="doc-upload-form js-form-uploadfile">
                                <button class="btn btn-info"
                                        type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('briefcaseFileUploader').click()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    {{ _('Add files') }}
                                </button>
                                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="briefcaseFileUploader" style="display: none;">
                                <button class="btn btn-info hide" type="submit">{{ _('Upload files') }}</button>
                            </form>

js:
$('#briefcaseFileUploader').change(function() {
        $('.js-form-uploadfile').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(".js-form-uploadfile");
            $.ajax({
                url:'/profile/uploadFiles',
                data: form.serialize(),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                method: 'POST',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#ajax-loader').show();
                    if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации данной задумки - стоит воспользоваться [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData)
Что-то типа :

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```